# How does SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) convert date and numeric values of different cultures?

Tags: sql-server, types, ssis, type-conversion, uiculture

I am still stuck after some research on the internet and hope someone can help me. **My goal is to bring in Microsoft SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS), date or numeric values with different formats (22.01.2023, 01/22/2023, ...) from different cultures (German, USA, etc.) into a consistent format.** What I have found out so far:

- When within a dataflow task a source component (e.g. OLE DB Source) extracts data from a database, the matching data types are mapped and convertet from the database by the dataflow engine to the corresponding SSIS data types. ([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/integration-services-data-types-in-expressions?view=sql-server-2017))
- I also know that e.g. SQL Server stores the date values only in bytes, which displays the date in the format of the set OS language on the graphical user interface = all date values are stored in the same format and are only converted to the corresponding set language format at the output for the user. ([Source](https://bornsql.ca/blog/how-sql-server-stores-data-types-datetime-date-time-and-datetime2/))
- Microsoft itself says: "However, the date is in the ISO format of YYYY-MM-DD, regardless of whether the locale preference uses the ISO format." ([Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/cast-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-2017#remarks))

**Does this mean that all date formats extracted into an SSIS package from source components are automatically converted to the ISO format and saved? So, do I no longer have to do the conversion of data formats from different cultures myself but can "leave it" to SSIS?**

I tried to extract data in different formats from excel or SQL Server tables but ended up in having automatically the ISO date format.

Comment: It depends entirely on your **actual** SSIS flow - which then depends entirely on the **actual** steps being performed: so there is no universal default for _all_ dates/times that enter an SSIS workflow. I do appreciate that many wizards and processes in SSIS are very... opaque and hide many important small details like how text-encoding, regional formatting, etc are handled - so please give us something more concrete to work with.

Comment: Example: I have two servers, one is located in Germany and stores the date in the German format 01/22/2023, the other server is located in the USA and stores the date in the format 01/22/2023. I then extract the data from both sources and want to automatically (by a transformation etc.) bring them into a consistent format. However, I am not sure if SSIS can automatically detect and convert different date formats without me having to use explicit conversion. Thats my only intension.

Comment: Assuming your SSIS workflow communicates with those servers using actual database connections (and not, say, web-services) then you would be working with native binary representation of dates/times so there is no format to speak of at all so your question is moot. However if your SSIS workflow actually needs to import or export dates/times in a particular human-readable format then you can specify that when you define your SSIS workflow steps.

Comment: I might miss something here, but as far as I know: if your data ist stored as date or numeric datatype, you don't have to take care of different countries etc. - it oly matters for the output. However, if your data is stored in an alphanumeric type such as varchar, you won't be able to automatically convert the data, since the order of YYYY, MM and DD in a date is not always the same (e.g. yyyy-mm-dd and yyyy-dd-mm).